# Laravel 5.3: Integrity constraint violation (works on some setups)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to accomplish a self-reference setup, so an user can add an object of identical type to it's relationel table.

It works perfectly on my local machine and on my staging environment, but on production it keeps returning an error. Local and staging runs php 7 and production runs php 5; but I dont think the error is related to this?

I really can't figure out why - so I'd really appreciate any help!

I've marked the specific line with (**Error**) that triggers the error.

Controller: **BasicCalculationController.php**

```
$bcItem   = BasicCalculation::with( 'unit' )->find( $id );

Error: $basicCalculation->basicCalculation()->save( $bcItem, [
                    'organization_id'      => $org->id,
                    'quantity'             => $quantity
] );
```

Model **BasicCalculation.php**:

```
public function basicCalculation() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Models\BasicCalculation', 'calculations_basic_calculations', 'calculation_id', 'basic_calculation_id' )->withPivot( 'organization_id', 'quantity' )->withTimestamps();
}
```

Works perfectly on local + staging. Dosen't work on production.

The error that is returned from MySQL is:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`calcueasy`.`calculations_basic_calculations`, CONSTRAINT `calculations_basic_calculations_calculation_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`calculation_id`) REFERENCES `calculations` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `calculations_basic_calculations` (`basic_calculation_id`, `calculation_id`, `created_at`, `organization_id`, `quantity`, `updated_at`) values (560, 38, 2018-11-08 10:06:13, 1, 22.00000, 2018-11-08 10:06:13)) in C:\laragon\www\CalcuEasy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:770
```

**Update:**

Production table:

[image]

Staging table:

[image]

Comment: You have error in relation on production server

Comment: @AdamKozlowski but they have exact same controller and model files.

Comment: Yes, but data in database is different. It must be problem in relation for sure. Some values are not suits to tables that have relations.

Comment: Try to write that relations again, maybe somewhere is unsigned value or int10 instead of int11

Comment: @AdamKozlowski I've updated my question. Please check the two tables. First is production, second is staging.

Comment: You've checked that you've got a record in your `calculations` table with `id = 38` ?

Comment: show also relations please